# Modulo gives impossible value

Tags: c++, modulo

I want a table of four values between 1 to 6.

I'm using: `rand() % 6 + 1;`

This should give values between 1 and 6.

Except if `rand()` generates the value 0.

1. I keep getting 7's. I don't want any 7's
2. What is the range of rand? How I prevent it from generation any 0 values?
3. Alternative solutions are quite welcome.
4. My teacher gave us the clue of using "random".
   We use Borland C++ Builder 5 at school.
   I am using Dev-C++ 5.3.0.3 at home.
   I find there are a few differences to how they work, which I find strange..
   I can't use random(), it gives me not declared in scope...

   ```
   int main (){

       int I;
       int Fasit[3];

       srand (time(NULL) );

       for(I=0; I<4; I++) {
           Fasit[I]=rand() % 6 + 1;
       }

       std::cout << Fasit[0] << " " << Fasit[1] << " " << Fasit[2] << " " << Fasit[3] << " ";

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Some values I get:

```
2 6 1 7  
5 2 1 4  
5 2 1 4  
5 2 1 4  
1 3 1 6  
5 3 3 7  
5 3 3 7  
5 3 3 7
```

7 shouldn't be possible, should it?

PS: I know my print is ham fisted, I will make it a bit more elegant once the number generation works.

Comment: How often do you expect `rand() == 0`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consdier these lines:

```
int Fasit[3];
for(I=0; I<4; I++) {
  Fasit[I]
```

You declare an array of three entries, which you write to **four** times.

Try your program again, but with:

```
int Fasit[4];
```

Comment: I was under the impression 3 meant: 0, 1, 2, 3 ?

Comment: @DrOnline No, 3 means the array has 3 elements.

Comment: @DrOnline when you initialize an array array[n], n is the number of values in the array. When you access it via index, it is zero indexed.

Comment: Alright, the 7's disappeared. Thanks. I wonder why the size of the table had that effect.

Comment: @DrOnline, Because undefined behaviour is inexplicable.

Comment: Thanks everybody. The program works now, and IBM just called wanting me to do some hardcore programming for them with my new skills. Sweet. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You only have 3 elements in Fasit[3]; When you write to Fasit[3], you are in the realm of undefined behavior, which in this case manifests it self with apparent contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! I had misunderstood the relationship between index and table size, I thought 3 means size 4 with, 0, 1, 2, 3...

Answer (score 2):

```
int Fasit[3];
```

You are creating an array of size 3, which can be accessed with indexes 0, 1 or 2 only.

You are writing and reading Fasit[3], which has an undefined behaviour. When a behaviour is undefined, you are bound to obtain weird results. This is it.

Comment: Thank you. This my first experience with this type of issue. Program works now!

Answer (score 2):

`Fasit[3]` allows you to access only `Fasit[0]`, `Fasit[1]`, and `Fasit[2]`.

Accessing `Fasit[3]`, *either for reading and writing, is undefined behavior*. Your code is both writing and reading to `Fasit[3]` :-). The program is accessing the array out-of-bound. Fix it!

As to why 7 is printed, that is just coincidence. Note that `Fasit[0-3]` is always printed in the range `1-6` as you expected.

See also:

- [Array Index out of bound in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-c)
- [Bounds checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking)

Comment: Good point about the 0 to 3 indexes being within the range. I did notice that but thought it was coincidental. Program works now!