# C programming arrays assistance?

Tags: c, arrays

Write c program where the user takes an array with n elements and finds the elements whose value is a multiple of the number 5.These elements are displays on screen along with their value like this :
V[i]=a ,V[j] = b,....
My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()

    {
        int n,i,sh=0;
        int v[100];
        printf ("Please write n:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        { printf ("\n Write the element %d",i);
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);
        }
        if (v[i] %5)
        printf("The element is a multiple of 5",&sh);

        return 0;
    }
```

It compiles perfectly,but when I run this and I write the elements,it does nothing..where am I wrong?

EDIT :

```
Yes,here it is :
Please write n: 4
Enter value 0: 10
Enter value 1 : 9
Enter value 2 : 20
Enter value 3:14

V[0]=10,V[2}=20
```

Comment: `if (v[i] %5)` is not inside the loop. it's going to always use the last value of `i`.

Comment: If you indent your code, you might see the problem. You do the `v[i] %5` check *outside* the loop, meaning you only do it once and you do it on an index one higher than the number of entered values.

Comment: I dont know why everyone downvotes these posts..

Comment: additionally `printf("The element is a multiple of 5",&sh);` is wrong

Comment: It is going to crash if user enters more than 100 when asked for n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three errors in your code.

- First `if ( v[i] % 5 )` is outside of the loop at the end, it will just try this once for `i = n+1`. You will have the [out-of-bound problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-c).
- And you search a multiple of `5` so the condition should be `if ( v[i] % 5 == 0 )`.
- After, your `printf` is also wrong.

  ```
  printf("The element is a multiple of 5",&sh);
  //                                     ^^^^
  ```

What is `sh` ? Why do you want to use it in `printf` ? You format string does not seem to want an argument.

Your code should look like this :

```
for ( i=0; i < n; i++ )
{
    printf( "\n Write the element %d", i );
    scanf( "%d", &v[i] );
    if ( v[i] % 5 == 0 )
        printf( "The element is a multiple of 5" );
}
```

EDIT :

With the out put example, maybe you should do another loop :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n, i, sh = 0; // I still don't for what sh is used ...
    int v[100];

    printf ("Please write n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    // Get the values
    for ( i=0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "\n Write the element %d", i );
        scanf( "%d", &v[i] );
    }

    // Print the values multiple of 5
    for ( i=0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( v[i] % 5 == 0 )
            printf( "V[%d]=%d\n", i, v[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[HERE](http://ideone.com/9P236j) is the example working.

Comment: + for check additional mistake in if condition

Comment: Thank you but I have to write ALL the numbers,and then it shows which is a multiple,not one by one..thank you anyway!

Comment: Do you have an example of the output you should get ?

Comment: It doesnt work at all,Im sorry..now when I write n = 4,I can only enter one value..

Comment: @user2685334 It works fine for me... Are you sure you copied this code correctly ?

Comment: @user2685334 I attached an example working after my example. http://ideone.com/9P236j

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if (v[i] %5)
    printf("The element is a multiple of 5",&sh);
```

After the first loop your `i` is equal to `n+1`. You don't reset it neither check your elements in a loop.
Also your format string doesn't have any `%p` in it, why do you pass `%sh`?

Do something like:

```
 for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    if (v[i] %5) // not divided by 5
       // Correct prtinf() statement 
       // printf("The element v[%d] = %d is NOT multiple of 5", i, v[i]);
```

Comment: To whoever edited my post - not necessarily index-out-of-bounds at this point. The loop goes up to n, which can be more, less or equal than array size (which is 100).

Answer (score 2):

1. The IF statement isn't in the loop
2. `printf("The element is a multiple of 5",&sh);` - am I missing something? (why the &sh?)
3. The IF statement isn't totally correct

**How would I edit it:**

```
 1|    #include <stdio.h>
 2|
 3|    int main ()        
 4|    {
 5|        int n,i,sh=0;
 6|        int v[100];
 7|        printf ("Please write n:");
 8|        scanf("%d",&n);
 9|        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
10|        { 
11|             printf ("\n Write the element %d",i);
12|             scanf("%d",&v[i]);
13|             
14|             if ((v[i] % 5) == 0)
15|                 printf("The %d. element %d is a multiple of 5", i+1, v[i]);
16|        }
17|
18|        return 0;
19|    }
```

Just wondering what is the purpose of variable **sh**? Or for what did the author wanted to use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    int n,i,sh=0;
    int v[100];
    printf ("Please write n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    { printf ("\n Write the element %d",i);
    scanf("%d",&v[i]);
    }

    /// now go back through the array
    //
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
       if( v[i] % 5 == 0 )
           printf( "The element at %d is %d, divisible by 5\n", i, v[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int n,i,sh=0;

```
//array to hold the numbers
int N[100];

//count of numbers
printf ("Enter the NUMBER count :");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

//get the input in an array
    for (i=0;i

```
//check for the divisibility
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
   if( N[i] % 5 == 0 )
       printf( "The element at %d is %d, divisible by 5\n", i, N[i] );

return 0;
```

}