# While/for loop error

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

Hi I made a post earlier though I believe it was quite ambiguous, so I'll try again and word it differently.

I'm trying to write a program that takes the input of two English numbers and converts them into integers (using arrays), runs the calculations then converts them back into English words.

For example:

User Input:
sixty_six + six
Output:
seventy_two

User Input:
forty_four - four
Output:
forty

etc

However I have been having trouble finding out the issue in my code, spent the last hour or so trying to find the problem, though I have not been able to. So hopefully someone here could help me out.

My code the `cout` are there so trank where in the loop it goes wrong, it seems run as intended up until the second cout line. meaning it outputs the `the token is forty` and `tens is euqal to` and then it fails and terminates:

```
nt Wordnum::read_number(string n) {
    int result_ten = 0;
    int result_unit = 0;
    int j = 0;

    //  Loops through input and turns it all to lower case.

    while (n[j]) {
        char c;

        c = n[j];
        c = (tolower(c));
        n[j] = c;
        j++;
    }

    string delimiter = "_";
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;

    // Checks for the _ delimiter and takes the first token then checks it against the array to "convert" from string to int.
    while ((pos = n.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
        token = n.substr(0, pos);

        cout << "Token is: '" << token << "'" << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (token == tens[i]) {
                result_ten = i * 10;
                n.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
                cout << "tens is equals to: " << result_ten << endl;
            } else if (token == units[i]) {
                result_unit = i;
                n.erase(0, pos);
            }
        }

        result_ten = (result_ten + result_unit);

        cout << "ten is equals to: " << result_ten << endl;
    }

    return result_ten;
}
```

The arrays that are in use:

```
string const Wordnum::units[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
    "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",
    "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};

string const Wordnum::tens[] = {"zero", " ", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
```

Thanks in advance. If something is unclear I'll try and explain it better.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step....

Comment: Please be aware, a std::string is no null terminated c-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int Wordnum::read_number(string n) {

```
int result_ten = 0;
int result_unit = 0;
int j = 0, f3 =0;
//  Loops through input and turns it all to lower case.
while (n[j]) {
    char c;

    c = n[j];
    c = (tolower(c));
    n[j] = c;
    j++;
}
string delimiter = "_";
size_t pos = 0, pos1 = 0;
string token;
// Checks for the _ delimiter and takes the first token then checks it against the    array to "convert" from string to int.

if((pos = n.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
    token = n.substr(0, pos);
}else
{
    token = n.substr(0, n.length());
    f3 = 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (token == tens[i]) {
       result_ten = i * 10;
       i=0;
       if(f3 == 1)
          break;
       token = n.substr(pos+1,(n.length()-pos-1) );
     } else if (token == units[i]) {
            result_unit = i;
            break;
     }
 }## End of loop for converting the string to int ##
 result_ten = (result_ten + result_unit);
 cout << "value is : " << result_ten << endl;
 return result_ten;
```

}

Please check this out, Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks a lot this works well, I need to remember to break out of things it seems.

Answer (score 3):

You try to index `tens[i]`, while I goes from [0,20).  However, there are not 20 indexes in tens.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in your *for-loop*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    //              ^^
    if (token == tens[i]) {
    //           ^^^^^^^
    // ...
}
```

`i` goes from `0` to `19` included. And you trying to index `tens[i]`. But:

```
string const Wordnum::tens[] = {"zero", " ", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
```

this line shows us that `tens` has only `10` elements. You have the famous [*out-of-bounds*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-c) error here.

You can solve this problem with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if ( i < 10 && token == tens[i]) {
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
}
```

I'm not sure your algorithm will give the result expected, but at least your program will not crash.