# typedef fixed length array -> auto-extended size?

Tags: c, string, malloc, typedef

I want to define a structure of fixed length string, like this:

```
typedef char str8[8];
```

so I can create **arrays of fixed length string** like:

```
str8 * mydata;
mydata = malloc(100 * sizeof(str8));
```

I am using mydata to store a list of names:
Peter
Waseels
Grumpy
Lexiunos
Beta
...

**Everything works fine until mydata[3], which becomes LexiunosBeta instead of Lexiunos. mydata[4] however is still beta only.**

**This seems to occur only when size(name) >= size(str8). I extend str8 to str10 as a temporary solution but I really want to know what the real problem is and how I could fix it.**

If I change typedef char str8[8] to a more robust definition like:
typedef {char * x;}str8; will it solve the problem?

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Out-of-range access of arrays will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Lexiunos` is 9 bytes counting the trailing `NUL` and your typedef is `char[8]`, you are writing outside the bounds of the array.

Take a look to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/671709/1606345):

> In this particular case, you are declaring a stack based array.
>   Depending upon the particular implementation, accessing outside the
>   bounds of the array will simply access another part of the already
>   allocated stack space (most OS's and threads reserve a certain portion
>   of memory for stack).

There is nothing like "auto-extend size" for the stack, use dynamic memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *arr[] = {"Peter",  "Waseels",  "Grumpy", "Lexiunos", "Beta", /*...*/};
    size_t size = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];
    char **mydata;
    size_t i;

    mydata = malloc(size * sizeof(*mydata));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        mydata[i] = malloc(strlen(arr[i]) + 1);
        if (mydata[i] == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(mydata[i], arr[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", mydata[i]);
        free(mydata[i]);
    }
    free(mydata);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification! Now I saw my mistake! Need to learn the good coding habit!