# Why not memory address of an array always increase?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Tried following code on 32 bit ubuntu virtual machine:

```
static int a[0x1f0fff];
cout << &a[0x600000] << endl;
cout << &a[0x800000] << endl;
cout << &a[0x8fff00000] << endl;

0x984a140
0xa04a140
0x7c4a140
```

Really confused that the address do not keep increasing.

The array located in heap, and what printed is virtual memory address. Is it because that it exceeds virtual memory space?

Besides, according to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/671709/2151275), the last two line codes are **indexing into a part of memory that is not allocated**. Why is there no segfault reported?

Comment: "Why is there no segfault reported?"   Segfaults happens when your program accesses memory it hasn't been allocated.  No segfault doesn't mean your program is ok.  Programs aren't required to crash as soon as you do something wrong.

Comment: No guarantees. This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Don't downvote questions because you think someone should already know the answer.   If you downvote a question, comment as to why.

Comment: OK, what output did you expect?

Comment: Thanks very much. I learned the rule.

Comment: @n.m. I thought the a[] operation will simply add two number together, and the address keep increasing. But it's undefined.

Comment: Undefined behavior: the compiler is allowed to spit out elephants from your computer. Or it can trigger segfault. Depends on its mood.

Comment: "Keep increasing" is not very specific. What *exact* numbers did you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hexadecimal notation, whilst flashy, is no more than an obfuscation (although the type inference rules for hexadecimal literals differ from denary literals).

The behaviour of your code is *undefined* but perhaps not for the reason that you might think.

Note that `&a[0x600000]` doesn't actually attempt to *dereference* the non-existent (0x600000)th element of `a` before taking the address of it. The compiler is required to evaluate the expression as `a + 0x600000`. **But:**

Setting a pointer to an address that is not an element within your array `a`, or one past the end of that array is undefined behaviour. As such the compiler is allowed to output anything.

Comment: Thank you. I got the logic. Undefined behavior is unreasonable. But have seen following code used many times:`#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE*)0)->MEMBER)`. Is this ok to use address 0?

Comment: @heLomaN: It's certainly OK in C (and idiomatic in C), I can't recall for C++. Perhaps ask it as a question.

Comment: @heLomaN: `offsetof` is part of your implementation, and must be because you can't write it yourself. As part of your implementation, your _particular_ implementation may use `(TYPE*)0` in this way. Another common implementation is `#define offsetof __builtin_offsetof`

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behaviour is not segfault.  You *hope* for segfault.  Sometimes you get nasal demons.

Why this particular behaviour?  32 bit unsigned math mod 2^32.  Not guaranteed to happen, but I am pretty certain that is what the compiled result is doing here.

Comment: Thank you. I shouldn't try undefined code. But the math is not right, 0xa04a140 + 0x8fff00000 - 0x800000 != 0x7c4a140. Might because undefined.

Comment: @helo mod 2^32 with a `*sizeof(int)` it does equal.  Pointer arithmetic has each `+1` adding `+sizeof(int)` here.

Answer (score 1):

> Besides, according to another answer, the last two line codes are indexing into a part of memory that is not allocated. Why is there no segfault reported?

Accessing array out-of-bound is undefined behaviour, that means anything can happen, and that also means there is NO guarantee of a segfault - it may happen one time, it may not happen the next time (that's why it's called undefined).