# Index of arrays are exceeding

Tags: c++, arrays, int

I am having problems with arrays it shows counting up to 127 when I execute the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x[5];
    int z=0;
    while(1)
    {
        x[z]=z;
        cout<<x[z];
        z++;
    }
}
```

**My problems**

1. If I had given the maximum indexes of array 'x[5]', then why it is not throwing an exception on exceeding the limit.
2. If it is exceeding, then it is stoped on the array's index 127 'x[127]'.

I'm using dev-c++ with TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Compiler.

Comment: There are no exceptions that will be thrown... And even if it was you aren't catching any either.. You can look into throwing your own by throwing: std::out_of_range. These are only thrown for std data structures (i.e. std::vector, etc.)

Comment: C just dont have an implicit bound checking feature. And why it stopped at 127 is probably that your operating system detected an invaild memory access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array index out of bound in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-c)

Comment: Look for the more information on array out of bound https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not a guaranteed memory exception when going out of bounds, it's merely undefined behavior. In your case it's a local variable so it's going to consistently walk through the stack until some undefined event either crashes or ends the program.

Comment: But why only 127 on Dev-Cpp. however, if I do write the same code using CodeBlocks. It shows the counting up to 73.

Comment: While when I globally declaring the array with index 5.

In Dev-Cpp, it shows counting up to 2543
In codeBlocks, it shows counting up to 277.

Comment: Well undefined behavior is exactly that, you can't know exactly how it's going to break things. In your case it's almost certainly all for the same reasons though. First two examples are walking up the stack (which grows downwards) and the exception hits based on how far from the top of the stack you are. Once reaching the top of the stack it will then move into a separate memory page which is likely invalid memory.

Comment: When defining it as a global it's the same explanation but you're moving through the .data section in your process. Once you get past the rest of the image in memory it's likely the next page is inaccessible.

Comment: Also note you're dealing with an array, so that index should be multiplied by 4 to see how far you've moved in memory. Your example using a global would be ``10,172`` bytes which sounds about right for a basic ``main`` image.