# how can i implement a function which can passin vector and int *?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to write a function which can modify element for all container which space is continueous, like, vector, int*. char* ....

here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void test(T* t, size_t size) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    // *(t + i * sizeof(size_t)) += 2;
    *(t + i * sizeof(size_t)) = *(t + i * sizeof(size_t)) + 2;
    // cout << *reinterpret_cast<int*>(t + sizeof(size_t) * i) << endl;
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
}

int main() {
  std::vector<size_t> a = {1,2,3,4};
  test(&a[0], 4);  // print result is: 3, 2,3,4, which only modify the first element
  int b[4] = {1,2,3,4};
  test(b, 4); // print result is: 3, 2,3,4, which only modify the first element
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    cout << a[i] << " ";
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    cout << b[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

please see the notes in code, i think when i use `*(t + i * sizeof(size_t))`, it will find the next int position, but it failed, can anyone help on this?

Comment: "I want to write a function which can modify element for all container which space is continueous, like, vector, int*. char*" Then do what the standard library does, and accept a pair of iterators (pointers are a kind of iterator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add `2` to each element of a collection, C++ already provides a way to do that:

```
std::vector<size_t> a = {1,2,3,4};
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), [](int i){ return i + 2; });
```

This has a few obvious advantages over your code:

1. it works with non-contiguous collections (as well as contiguous ones)
2. it separates the iteration from the operation carried out one each item
3. it's already debugged and heavily tested

Comment: @xyhuang  I think `std::for_each` is the better candidate if you weren't planning to put them in another container.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to multiply the offset by `sizeof(size_t)` in this expression:

```
*(t + i * sizeof(size_t))
```

Since the type of the pointer is known to be `T`, adding `i` to the pointer will point it at the next object. So you can just do:

```
*(t + i)
```

Of course, the usual way to write that is:

```
t[i]
```

---

Also, this call is incorrect:

```
std::vector<size_t> a = {1,2,3,4};
test(&a[0], 4);
```

If you want to treat the `vector` as an array like you're doing, you need to use the `data` method like this:

```
test(a.data(), 4);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jG5EW1).

Comment: thanks a lot, i think it's a simple question, just forget the simple way. thank you very much

Comment: @xyhuang See the update. Your call using vector is wrong.

Comment: one more question, when i call *(t + i * sizeof(size_t)) ，i think it will visit unknown memory address, why it is not crashed(like segment fault)

Comment: @xyhuang Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-c) to find out reason of not crash.